# Windows: Cannot find -lz

Tags: c++, windows, g++, zlib

I am trying to compile cpp source files and link with zlib library using the command

```
g++ $SRC_FILES -lz -o src
```

where

```
$SRC_FILES = "Source1.cpp\
              Source2.cpp\
              Source3.cpp"
```

When I try it on Linux it builds perfectly. But the same doesn't build in Windows. And I get an error saying

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed cygwin and used g++ from the one provided in cygwin.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: You need to install zlib obviously. Use cygwin package manager

Comment: Thanks a lot @M.M It worked fine. Previously, I had simply installed zlib after downloading from their [website](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zlib.htm). But it should have been installed with cygwin package manager as you said. Thanks a lot